# gcovr - Is there a known issue with corrupting filenames in xml coverage Cobertura reports?

Tags: c++, python, code-coverage, sonarqube

I'm working on a C++ project to integrate with gcovr coverage reports. I'm running into an issue where a pacakge entry is getting added to the gcovr report twice for the same file, which is causing an error in the reporting server.

However, when looking at the gcovr xml output, the second time the file is output, the filename attribute is actually corrupted with a double "//" and the name attribute is corrupted in a similar fashion the same place with a double "..".

Here's a quick example of what the corrupted entry looks like with the names replaced with foo and bar appropriately:

```
<package branch-rate="0.0" complexity="0.0" line-rate="1.0" name="foo.foo.foo.foo..bar.bar">
    <classes>
        <class branch-rate="0.0" complexity="0.0" filename="foo/foo/foo/foo//bar/bar/foobar.h" line-rate="1.0" name="foobar_h">
            <lines>
                <line branch="false" hits="612" number="37"/>
            </lines>
        </class>
    </classes>
</package>
```

This appears to be a legitmate bug in gcovr. Has anyone encountered this before and if so, know of the fix or if the fix is in a newer release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a bug in gcovr. Upgrading to a stable revision with the fix corrected the issue.